# php delete a single file in directory

Tags: php

I've got the php list directory script from this link http://www.gaijin.at/en/scrphpfilelist.php.
How do I delete a single file from the directoy? I tried `unlink`, but it deleted all the files from that directory. this the short code what i got from the link!

```
while ($file = readdir ($hDir)) {
if ( ($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && (substr($file, 0, 1) != '.') &&
     (strtolower($file) != strtolower(substr($DescFile, -(strlen($file))))) &&
     (!IsFileExcluded($Directory.'/'.$file))
   ) {

  array_push($FilesArray, array('FileName' => $file,
                                'IsDir' => is_dir($Directory.'/'.$file),
                                'FileSize' => filesize($Directory.'/'.$file),
                                'FileTime' => filemtime($Directory.'/'.$file)
                                ));
}
}
$BaseDir = '../_cron/backup';
$Directory = $BaseDir;

foreach($FilesArray as $file) {
  $FileLink = $Directory.'/'.$file['FileName'];
  if ($OpenFileInNewTab) $LinkTarget = ' target="_blank"'; else $LinkTarget = '';
    echo '<a href="'.$FileLink.'">'.$FileName.'</a>';
    echo '<a href="'.unlink($FileLink).'"><img src="images/icons/delete.gif"></a></td>';
  }
}
```

the list directory folder call : backup.
in the `unlink($FileLink)`, when i hover the link has change to another folder to admin folder?

Comment: Could you post the code you tried please?

Comment: you used unlink inside a loop so everything inside loop is gone.

Comment: @experimentX any idea how to put `unlink` without deleting all the files

Comment: yes... i do see update in 5 min

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`unlink('path_to_filename');` will delete one file at a time.

If your whole files from directory is gone means you listed all files and deleted one by one in a loop.

Well you cannot de delete in the same page. You have to do with other page. create a page called `deletepage.php` which will contain script to delete and link to that page with 'file' as parameter.

```
foreach($FilesArray as $file)
{
    $FileLink = $Directory.'/'.$file['FileName'];

    if($OpenFileInNewTab) $LinkTarget = ' target="_blank"'; 
    else $LinkTarget = '';

    echo '<a href="'.$FileLink.'">'.$FileName.'</a>';
    echo '<a href="deletepage.php?file='.$fileName.'"><img src="images/icons/delete.gif"></a></td>';        
}
```

On the deletepage.php

```
//and also consider to check if the file exists as with the other guy suggested.
$filename = $_GET['file']; //get the filename
unlink('DIRNAME'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename); //delete it
header('location: backto prev'); //redirect back to the other page
```

If you don't want to navigate, then use ajax to make elegant.

Comment: Voila, you've created a gaping security hole. People can delete whatever they want if they just fiddle with the `file` parameter.

Comment: I know it's a kinda old answer but this is the accepted aswer and it shouldn't... You should always check if the file exists and if it's a file, not a directory, it's even better to check for the type of file you are deleting.

Answer (score 13):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Unlink can safely remove a single file; just make sure the file you are removing it actually a file and not a directory ('.' or '..')

```
if (is_file($filepath))
  {
    unlink($filepath);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply You Can Use It

```
    $sql="select * from tbl_publication where id='5'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $res=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //Getting File Name From DB
    $pdfname = $res1['pdfname'];
    //pdf is directory where file exist
    unlink("pdf/".$pdfname);
```

Comment: Why did you introduce database queries in your answer?

Comment: @NicoHaase That's simple example of getting resources. Ultimately there is deleting code, getting files are just sources. Down vote is not expected!

Answer (score 3):

[unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) is the right php function for your use case.

```
unlink('/path/to/file');
```

Without more information, I can't tell you what went wrong when you used it.

Answer (score 3):

The script you downloaded lists the content of a specified folder. You probably put the unlink - call in one of the `while`-loops that list the files.

EDIT - Now that you posted your code:

```
echo '<a href="'.unlink($FileLink).'"><img src="images/icons/delete.gif"></a></td>';
```

Doing this calls the `unlink`-function each time the line is written, deleting your file.
You have to write a link to a script that contains a delete function and pass some parameter that tells your script what to delete.

Example:

```
<a href="/path/to/script.php?delete='. $FileLink .'">delete</a>
```

You **should not** pass the path to a file this script and just delete it though, because malevolent being might use it to just delete everything or do other evil things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a single file, you must, as you found out, use the [**`unlink()`**](https://www.php.net/unlink) function.

That function will delete what you pass it as a parameter : so, it's up to you to pass it the **path to the file** that it must delete.

For example, you'll use something like this :

```
unlink('/path/to/dir/filename');
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $delurl=$_GET['delete'];
        unlink($delurl);
    }
?>
```

```php
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<a href=\"$entry\">$entry</a> | <a href=\"?delete=$entry\">Delete</a><br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

This is It

Answer (score 0):

```php
// This code was tested by me (Helio Barbosa)

    // this directory (../backup) is for try only.
    // it is necessary create it and put files into him.

    $hDir = '../backup';
    if ($handle = opendir( $hDir )) {
        echo "Manipulador de diretório: $handle\n";
        echo "Arquivos:\n";

        /* Esta é a forma correta de varrer o diretório */
        /* Here is the correct form to do find files into the directory */
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            // echo($file . "</br>");
            $filepath = $hDir . "/" . $file ;
            // echo( $filepath . "</br>" );
            if(is_file($filepath))
            {
                echo("Deleting:" . $file . "</br>");
                unlink($filepath);
            }           
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Maybe you could add an English explanation of your code so other may understand?